# SQL to subtract 30 mins from current time and output time should be military format 153010 only time part

Tags: sql

SQL to subtract 30 mins from current time and output time should be military format 153010 only time part

Comment: Which database?

Comment: Date manipulations in SQL are usually highly database specific.  Please update your question and tell us which database you are using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle you can do this with:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE - 1 / 24 / 2, 'HH24MISS') FROM DUAL
```

Adding 1 to a date would increase by a date, 1/24 by an hour, and 1/24/2 by 30 min.

Please note that SYSDATE will give you the time of the server which would normally by UTC. If you want the local time you have to CURRENT_DATE.

Comment: It should be 

    SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE - 1 / 24 / 2, 'HH24MISS') FROM DUAL;